# How to print multi step webform current step number from webform page template?

Tags: 8, theming, webforms

I have template named `page--webform.tpl.twig` which is kind of wrapper for multistep webform. I would like to print current step of the webform from that template.

Is there a way to access current step number from this template?

Comment: On the page level? But why?

Comment: Not my decision. Front-ender organized templates that way.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll try to convince front-ender to move the code to another template then. Would drupal/web/modules/contrib/webform/templates/webform-progress-tracker.html.twig be the right one?